# Parse and process CSV in Django

Tags: python, django, csv

Apologies in advance since I'm new to Django (and I've also had to freshen up my Python skills). I'm trying to make a simple example of uploading a file through a form and then printing the rows in my terminal (as a test before doing some actual processing). My views.py contains the following:

```
def upload_csv(request):
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, "portal/csvupload.html")
    csv_file = request.FILES["csv_file"]
    handle_files(csv_file)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("portal:csvupload"))

def handle_files(csvfile):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

Now this returns an error message saying "**expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile**", and I'm unsure what's wrong with the code based on the error message? From a Python perspective it looks fine I think, but perhaps it's something to do with the re-direct? Apperciate all answers

Comment: just a tip: if request.method == "GET":

Comment: Apologies, silly mistake from my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.FILES["csv_file"]` is returning an `InMemoryUploadedFile` object and `csv.reader` does not know how to handle such an object. I believe you need to call the object's `read` method: `handle_files(csv_file.read())`. Note the [warning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.read) in the documentation: "Be careful with this method: if the uploaded file is huge it can overwhelm your system if you try to read it into memory. You’ll probably want to use chunks() instead; see below."

Comment: Also, thanks for the advice to split the csv file. Will implement that as soon as I can manage to read it :)

Comment: I've tried using csv_file.read().decode('utf-8'), and while it executes the code it creates a new line for every character in the csv file. Is there any other encoding you recommend?

Comment: Try `csv_file.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()` so you have a list of lines instead of a string.