# Storing data from csv file into model in django?

Tags: python, django, csv

I am submitting csv file from form using `POST` method and want to save its content into model
forms.py

```
class SaveCsvForm(forms.Form):
     upload_file = forms.FileField(label="Uplaod CSV File", help_text="Uploa file in CSV format")
```

Views.py

```
def save_csv(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SaveCsvForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        print("All ok I am check One")
        # instance = CsvStorage(file_field=request.FILES['file'])
        file = request.FILES['upload_file'].read()
        print(file)
        csv_to_db(file)
        ack = {
            'status': 'Success',
            'message': 'Data is successfuly submited into database'
        }
        return JsonResponse(ack)
    else:
        ack = {
            'status': 'Error',
            'message': 'Server Returned '+form.errors.as_json(),
        }
        return JsonResponse(ack)
else:
    form = SaveCsvForm()
    return render(request, 'upload_csv.html', {'form': form})
```

file handler method for storing data in Model

```
def csv_to_db(filename):
  with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    ''' reading csv file in dictionary format  '''
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        instance = CsvStorage(username=row['username'],
                              first_name=row['user'],
                              city=row['city'],
                              mobile=row['mobile']
                              )
        instance.save()
        if instance:
            return({'status': 'successfuly'})
        else:
            return({'status': 'error'})
```

Note:

1.The main problem is while reading the file

2.I don't want to store file in models `fileField`

Comment: try to remove the with`open(filename, 'r') as file:` and use `reader = csv.DictReader(filename)`

Comment: @BearBrown It's not working.... Actually File fetched from `POST` request is plain text

Comment: what does it mean not working?

Comment: @BearBrown `request.FILES['upload_file'].read()` returns content of file instaed of file object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50457222/parse-and-process-csv-in-django

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `FileSystemStorage` class in Django as described in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/storage/).